# Gnome Shell crashing continuously

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and for two weeks the gnome shell crashing continuously.

I went to the terminal and ran `dmesg` and this line was red:

> gnome-shell[1878]: segfault at e8 ip 00007ffb0d9486a2 sp 00007ffe68c9a088 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.1800.9[7ffb0d90b000+d4000]

Also, I'm getting too much of this message inside my log:

> (gnome-shell:1878): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion 'handler_id > 0' failed

At the 1:59 gnome-shell crashed and this is the logs for that time:

```
Nov 20 01:59:00 ICE-System chromium-browser.desktop[24367]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Nov 20 01:59:00 ICE-System chromium-browser.desktop[24367]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Nov 20 01:59:00 ICE-System chromium-browser.desktop[24367]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/infinality/conf.d/41-repl-os-win.conf", line 148: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Nov 20 01:59:00 ICE-System chromium-browser.desktop[24367]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/infinality/conf.d/41-repl-os-win.conf", line 160: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Nov 20 01:59:00 ICE-System dbus[971]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Nov 20 01:59:00 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: (gnome-shell:1878): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_window: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Nov 20 01:59:00 ICE-System kernel: [25172.518523] show_signal_msg: 19 callbacks suppressed
Nov 20 01:59:00 ICE-System kernel: [25172.518527] gnome-shell[1878]: segfault at e8 ip 00007ffb0d9486a2 sp 00007ffe68c9a088 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.1800.9[7ffb0d90b000+d4000]
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: gnome-session-binary[1824]: WARNING: Application 'gnome-shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System gnome-session-binary[1824]: WARNING: Application 'gnome-shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0): connected
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: (gnome-shell:24634): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:104: Failed to import: Error opening file: No such file or directory
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Nov 20 01:59:31 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: current session already has an ibus-daemon.
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System dbus[971]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service'
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System systemd[1]: Starting Location Lookup Service...
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System dbus[971]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System systemd[1]: Started Location Lookup Service.
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System dbus[971]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' (using servicehelper)
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: No permission to trigger offline updates: Polkit.Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: loading user theme: /usr/share/themes/Arc-Dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: [impatience] enabled
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: [impatience] enabled
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: [impatience] setting new speed: 1.25
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: [impatience] setting new speed: 1.25
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/infinality/conf.d/41-repl-os-win.conf", line 148: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/infinality/conf.d/41-repl-os-win.conf", line 160: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0): connected
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung SyncMaster (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1560]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: (gnome-shell:24634): St-WARNING **: length values must specify a unit
Nov 20 01:59:32 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: (gnome-shell:24634): St-WARNING **: length values must specify a unit
Nov 20 01:59:33 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: (gnome-shell:24634): St-WARNING **: Ignoring length property that isn't a number at line 732, col 24
Nov 20 01:59:33 ICE-System AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon
Nov 20 01:59:33 ICE-System org.freedesktop.PackageKit[971]: 01:59:33 AptDaemon [INFO]: Initializing daemon
Nov 20 01:59:33 ICE-System AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Initializing PackageKit compat layer
Nov 20 01:59:33 ICE-System org.freedesktop.PackageKit[971]: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/pkworker.py:35: PyGIWarning: PackageKitGlib was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PackageKitGlib', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
Nov 20 01:59:33 ICE-System org.freedesktop.PackageKit[971]:   from gi.repository import PackageKitGlib as pk
Nov 20 01:59:33 ICE-System org.freedesktop.PackageKit[971]: 01:59:33 AptDaemon.PackageKit [INFO]: Initializing PackageKit compat layer
Nov 20 01:59:33 ICE-System dbus[971]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Nov 20 01:59:34 ICE-System gnome-shell[24634]: GNOME Shell started at Mon Nov 20 2017 01:59:32 GMT+0330
Nov 20 01:59:47 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: (gnome-shell:24634): St-WARNING **: Ignoring length property that isn't a number at line 732, col 24
Nov 20 01:59:47 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: message repeated 2 times: [ (gnome-shell:24634): St-WARNING **: Ignoring length property that isn't a number at line 732, col 24]
Nov 20 01:59:49 ICE-System org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[1665]: (gnome-control-center-search-provider:25238): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:104: Failed to import: Error opening file: No such file or directory
Nov 20 01:59:49 ICE-System org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[1665]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Nov 20 01:59:49 ICE-System org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[1665]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Nov 20 01:59:51 ICE-System gnome-session[1824]: (gnome-shell:24634): St-WARNING **: Ignoring length property that isn't a number at line 732, col 24
Nov 20 01:59:51 ICE-System org.gnome.Logs[1665]: (gnome-logs:25420): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:104: Failed to import: Error opening file: No such file or directory
Nov 20 01:59:51 ICE-System org.gnome.Logs[1665]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Nov 20 01:59:51 ICE-System org.gnome.Logs[1665]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Nov 20 01:59:51 ICE-System org.gnome.Logs[1665]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/infinality/conf.d/41-repl-os-win.conf", line 148: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Nov 20 01:59:51 ICE-System org.gnome.Logs[1665]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/infinality/conf.d/41-repl-os-win.conf", line 160: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Nov 20 01:59:51 ICE-System org.gnome.Logs[1665]: (gnome-logs:25420): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkListBox with a model will ignore sort and filter functions
```

What is wrong with my gnome shell? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A bug has been filed to launchpad, seems like not much activity / response however ..

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1580605